# Show two different div on hover with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'll just keep it short. I want a the black div to disappear when `mouseout` the red div which not like that now. The problem now is that I also want the black div to still show when mouse is on it too.
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qc1rvsp0/)

Comment: When it says that you have to add code with your jsfiddle don't avoid it and put the link inside a code tag. The reason they ask for that it's for futur reference when jsfiddle will be deleted and someone face the same problem as you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mouseout as you said yourself like this
https://jsfiddle.net/xknc5x4h/

```
$('.red').mouseout(function() {
    $('.black').hide(200);
})
```

UPDATE: changed the code to your preferences: https://jsfiddle.net/2L5s7ude/

```
$('.red').hover(function() {
$('.black').show(200);
}, function() {
        if(!$('.black').is(":hover")) {
        $('.black').hide(200);
    }
});

$('.black').mouseout(function (e) {
    $(this).hide(200);
});
```

Comment: But when you hover over the black div the show hide process keep looping. I also want the black div to still show when hover on it too.

Comment: @WaiLinAung
Alright. I've updated my answer. It will stay shown when you're hovering over black as well and hide when leaving either red or black.

Comment: Thanks jquery way is more suite for what I'm doing now

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this, and the black div will appear on hover and disappear on mouseout :

```
$('.red').hover(function() {
    $('.black').show(200);
}, function() {
    $('.black').hide(200);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mouseout following is the code.

```js
$('.red').hover(function() {
 $('.black').show(200);
}, function() {
 
  $('.black').hover(function() {
   $('.red').trigger('hover');
    $('.black').show(200);
  }, function() {
   $('.red').off('hover');
    $('.black').hide(200);
  });
  
});
```

```css
.red,
.black,
.green {
  height: 4rem;
  width:10rem;
  line-height: 4rem;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.black {
  display: none;
  background: #333;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
  Hover me
</div>

<div class="black">
  Its me
</div>
<div class="green">
  Green
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is like css problem i do it quick fix 
you can try

https://jsfiddle.net/qc1rvsp0/4/

```js
$( ".red" ).hover(
  function() {
     $('.black').show(200);
  }, function() {
    $('.black').hide(200);
  }
);
```

```css
.wrapper {
    width:10rem;
}

.red,
.black,
.green {
  height: 4rem;
  line-height: 4rem;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.black {
  display: none;
  background: #333;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="red">
  Hover me
</div>

<div class="black">
  Its me
</div>
<div class="green">
  Green
</div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's not css problem. I want the black div to still showing when hover on the black div itself too

Comment: @WaiLinAung oh sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish it just with CSS, using `hover` pseudoclass and `+` selector. Using your html structure:

```
<div class="red">Hover me</div>
<div class="black">Its me</div>
<div class="green">Green</div>
```

You can use the next styles for hiding/showing black on red/black hover:

```
.red:hover + .black {
    display: block;
}
.black:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

I've modified your jsfiddle for testing [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qc1rvsp0/5/). With this option you can avoid importing jQuery, and make your web lighter. With css you could also add some effect for instance combining max-height and opacity if you need it

Comment: Thank I was searching for this. ;)